# SelectItems of SelectOneMenu always null

Tags: java, hibernate, jsf

When I print the selected item in the console , it is always returned as null

here is the method that create the SelectItem in my ManagedBean:

```
public List<String> getlisteMatricule() throws HibernateException
{
    List<String> matricules = new ArrayList<String>();



    for (Vehicule v : vehiculedao.getAll())
    {
        matricules.add(v.getMatricule());
        System.out.println(v.getMatricule());
    }
    return matricules ;
}


public List<SelectItem> getAllMatricules()
{
    List<SelectItem> options = new ArrayList<SelectItem>();
    List<String> listMatricules = getlisteMatricule();

    for (String mat : listMatricules)
    {  

        options.add(new SelectItem(mat));
        System.out.println("items = " + new SelectItem(mat));
    }
    return options ;
}
```

And here is my variables in my model which contain the getter and the setters and the constructor:

```
public class Program
{ 
private int id_progf;
private int nbrHeure;
private float montantGlobal;
private String commentaire;
private int cin_mon;
private String matricule;
private int cin_cand;

///gettersand setters
  ....   }
```

The methode that bring the variables from the database (List)

```
@Override
public Vehicule getMatricule(String matricule) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    Vehicule v=(Vehicule)session.get(Vehicule.class, matricule);
    return v;
}
```

And finally my xhtml file, it contains the form:

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2" >

                        <h:outputText value="Moniteur :" />
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="listeNomPrenom" title="Nom et Prenom"  value="{#programMB.np}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{moniteurMB.allNomPrenom}" />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:outputText value="Vehicule :" />
                        <h:selectOneMenu id="ListeMatricules" title="Matricules" value="{#programMB.program.matricule}">
                            <f:selectItems value="#{vehiculeMB.allMatricules}"  />
                        </h:selectOneMenu>

                        <h:outputText value="Nombre heures:" />
                        <p:inputText value="#{programMB.program.nbrHeure}" />


            </h:panelGrid>

              <p:commandButton  value="Save" action="#{programMB.ajouterProg}" />
```

Comment: This seems to be wrong: value="{#programMB.np}". You should have the # before braces

Comment: If `vehiculedao.getAll()` returns an empty list, why exactly do you think that the problem is in JSF side? Isn't it more logical that the problem is actually in the code behind that `getAll()` method? All that JSF code is then pure noise and you should rewrite the question in such way that it's asked in Hibernate context.

Comment: On an unrelated note: please stop doing business logic in getter methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first look, I saw the problem is in the `value` attribute of both of your selectOneMenu bellow:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="listeNomPrenom" title="Nom et Prenom"  value="{#programMB.np}">
               <f:selectItems value="#{moniteurMB.allNomPrenom}" />
         </h:selectOneMenu>
```

and:

```
        <h:selectOneMenu id="ListeMatricules" title="Matricules" value="{#programMB.program.matricule}">
                 <f:selectItems value="#{vehiculeMB.allMatricules}"  />
         </h:selectOneMenu>
```

In both of them you just putted `#` in the wrong place. change `value="{#programMB.np}"` to `value="#{programMB.np}"` and `value="{#programMB.program.matricule}"` to `value="#{programMB.program.matricule}"` and it should work for you!

Comment: thk you indeed this was the hole problem , and it was a sensible mistake that i didn't figure .
thank Sazzadur Rahaman :)